# Oracle Stored Procedure with Alter command

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to build an Oracle stored procedure which will accept a table name as a parameter.  The procedure will then rebuild all indexes on the table.

My problem is I get an error while using the ALTER command from a stored procedure, as if PLSQL does not allow that command.

Comment: Can you post the offending code?

Comment: The ORA error would be good to know, along with the version of Oracle you are using in addition to the code you're attempting to use.

Comment: Just curious, how did the answer you accepted actually answer your question?

Comment: Hi Will, this site is not only a Q-and-A forum, it is also a wiki - intended to help everyone. People around the world are helped, not only by those who answer questions, but also by those (like yourself) who *ask* questions. You can help others by adding details like the ORA error and Oracle version, and when you accept an answer, explain how that answer helped you.
Share and enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of possibilities.  First, you would have to treat the SQL as dynamic SQL.  Second, Oracle DDL statements cannot be run in a transaction (or, they terminate the current transaction and cannot themselves be rolled back).  This may affect whether you can use them in stored procedures, or where you can use stored procedures that contain them.

If none of the above apply at all - there could easily be something else astray - I suggest posting some code.

Answer (score 12):

Use the `execute immediate` statement to execute DDL inside PL/SQL.

```
create procedure RebuildIndex(index_name varchar2) as
begin
   execute immediate 'alter index ' || index_name || ' rebuild';
end;
```

I tested this code; it works.

Answer (score 4):

[Documentation.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#CHDIEFCJ)

**Passing Schema Object Names As Parameters**

> Suppose you need a procedure that
>   accepts the name of any database
>   table, then drops that table from your
>   schema. You must build a string with a
>   statement that includes the object
>   names, then use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to
>   execute the statement:

```
CREATE TABLE employees_temp AS SELECT last_name FROM employees;
CREATE PROCEDURE drop_table (table_name IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || table_name;
END;
/
```

> Use concatenation to build the string,
>   rather than trying to pass the table
>   name as a bind variable through the
>   USING clause.
>
> In addition, if you need to call a
>   procedure whose name is unknown until
>   runtime, you can pass a parameter
>   identifying the procedure. For
>   example, the following procedure can
>   call another procedure (drop_table) by
>   specifying the procedure name when
>   executed.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE run_proc (proc_name IN VARCHAR2, table_name IN VARCHAR2) ASBEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CALL "' || proc_name || '" ( :proc_name )' using table_name;
END;
/
```

> If you want to drop a table with the
>   drop_table procedure, you can run the
>   procedure as follows. Note that the
>   procedure name is capitalized.

```
CREATE TABLE employees_temp AS SELECT last_name FROM employees;
BEGIN 
  run_proc('DROP_TABLE', 'employees_temp'); 
END;
/
```