# Stored procedure weird error in oracle

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to the stored procedure in oracle and my simple code wont compile in oracle toad.

Here is my code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6YQO.png)

There is a readline under the `ALTER`, and it says "Found: "ALTER", expecting select or (: BEGIN BASE COSE...) " why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle Stored Procedure with Alter command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502302/oracle-stored-procedure-with-alter-command)

Comment: It is better form to include the problem code in your question. Posting it as an image (particularly at a third-party site) means that others that face the same problem can't find your question (and it's eventual answer) from a search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle doesn't allow you to use DDL natively in PL/SQL. To work around this, you can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to run the DDL as a dynamic query.